# Rtools error when attempting to download packages, even though I've installed Rtools

Tags: r, package, lib, install.packages, rtools

I am unable to download any packages in Rstudio because it says that the packages I'm trying to install (ggplot2, tidyverse) required Rtools required to build the packages even though I have Rtools. The following error pops up like this:

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/CE/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling several times. I have no idea how to fix this. I'm new to windows and I fear it would be that my folder for R, Rstudio and Rtools are in different places in my C:, but I followed tutorials about where to store each of those following multiple tutorials on how to install each of the programs.

Comment: Which version of Rtools do you have installed? Where is it installed? Can you find that path within the output from `Sys.getenv("PATH")`? If you happen to have `devtools` installed, does `devtools::find_rtools()` or `pkgbuild::has_rtools()` find something?

Comment: I downloaded Rtools44. I have zero packages installed, as I'm downloading R for the first time on a new computer, so I can't attempt the devtools suggestion. When I look for the pack, it spits this out a series of locations: '[1] "c:\\rtools43\\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\\bin;c:\\rtools43\\usr\\bin;\\usr\\bin;\\usr\\bin;C:\\R\\R-4.3.3\\bin\\x64;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\Program Files'

Comment: You're running R-4.3, therefore you must use Rtools43, not Rtools44. See https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/

Comment: Thank you, that's a great tip. I uninstalled and reinstalled, restarted Rstudio and tried to install ggplot2 again. This is the output: Installing package into ‘C:/Users/pinkp/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3:
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/PACKAGES'
installing the source package ‘ggplot2’
And then some more that I can't fit.

Comment: That sounds like your network is having problems, since even as I click that link here it works just fine. Can you click on either of those links and get a valid non-error return? If you can but still cannot get it to work in R, it might be that you have a firewall on your system that is permitting that URL for browsers but not for R. If not on your local machine, then perhaps your school/office/ISP?

Comment: If that's the case is there no way to get this to work? I'm trying to look at my browser security settings and I just turned off my browsing protection but it still didn't work.

Comment: Security controls put in place for a web browser have nothing to do with the R language, `Rterm.exe`, RStudio, or similar. If this is your computer, then you have control over the firewall, do your research on that. If you don't have a firewall application that you know of, then see if somebody else (using R) on your same network has the same problems that you do. If they do, then go to your network administrators (work/school) and ask what restrictions they may be imposing.

Comment: As an alternative, perhaps it's just _that_ URL. Try using https://packagemanager.posit.co (instructions are there).

Comment: If you mean the directions for changing my primary CRAN repository, I did that. I got this error following after trying to install ggplot2 again: Installing package into ‘C:/Users/pinkp/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/latest/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/ggplot2_3.5.0.zip'
Content type 'binary/octet-stream' length 4831654 bytes (4.6 MB)
downloaded 4.6 MB

package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
 C:\Users\CE\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpU5YfAd\downloaded_packages

Comment: Which seemed like it worked, but then when I tried to call it with library("ggplot2") it said this: Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘munsell’

Comment: Is there a way to download directly from the repository you linked? I searched ggplot2 in the website and it took me to an info page but no download link. I appreciate your help.

Comment: There are download links, and yes you can download and install individual packages. A complication you'll like run into is that a package may have one or more dependencies that you don't have installed (and `ggplot2` had a few). Your can see them listed at the top under `Imports:`, down them too.